# How to upload pdf file in MySQL without having to save it in desktop using c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, pdf, file-upload, printing

I'm using this class to print the pdf files:  
https://github.com/vijaythapa333/DGVPrinter/blob/master/DGVPrinter.cs
Everything works fine I just can't find a way to upload the pdf file without having to save it on desktop. I think that to upload there needs a location. Do u have any idea? Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.
Code for Upload method

```
#region Upload PdfFile Method
        public void UploadFile(string file, int BILL_ID,int Customer_ID,decimal Grand_Total,DateTime Date)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myconnstrng);
            conn.Open();
            FileStream fstream = File.OpenRead(file);
            byte[] contents = new byte[fstream.Length];
            fstream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fstream.Length);
            fstream.Close();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Insert into PdfFiles(File,BILL_ID,Customer_ID,Grand_Total,Date) values(@File,@BILL_ID,@Customer_ID,@Grand_Total,@Date)", conn)) 
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@File", contents);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BILL_ID", BILL_ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_ID", Customer_ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grand_Total", Grand_Total);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Finished Uploading Files");
            conn.Close();
        }
        #endregion
```

Main file

```
if (success == true)
                {
                    //Transaction Complete
                    //File Creation

                    MessageBox.Show("Transaction Completed Sucessfully");

                    //Print
                    DGVPrinter printer = new DGVPrinter();

                    printer.Title = "\r\n\r\n\r\n Supermarket Management System \r\n\r\n";
                    printer.SubTitle = "Client ID: " + txtClientID.Text + " \r\n" + "You were served by " + txtStaffName.Text + " \r\n" + string.Format("Date: {0}", DateTime.Now.Date) + " \r\n\r\n";
                    printer.SubTitleFormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.LineLimit | StringFormatFlags.NoClip;
                    printer.PageNumbers = false;
                    printer.PageNumberInHeader = false;
                    printer.PorportionalColumns = true;
                    printer.HeaderCellAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                    printer.Footer = "Grand Discount: " + txtGrandDiscount.Text + " \r\n" + "Grand Total: " + txtGrandTotal.Text + "\r\n\r\n" + "Paid Amount: " + txtPaidAmount.Text + " \r\n" + "Returned Amount: " + txtReturnedAmount.Text + "\r\n" + "Payment Type: " + cmbPaymentType.Text + " \r\n" + "Thank you for doing business with us.";
                    printer.FooterSpacing = 15;
                    printer.PrintMargins.Bottom = 200;
                    printer.PrintMargins.Top = 100;
                    
                    printer.PrintDataGridView(dgvAddedProducts);
                    
                    //Clear the Data Grid View and Clear all the Textboxes
                    dgvAddedProducts.DataSource = null;
                    dgvAddedProducts.Rows.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Smth wrong!!!!!");
                }
    //Upload
                using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "PDF Documents (*.pdf)|*.pdf", ValidateNames = true })
                {
                    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to upload this file?", "Klea", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                        if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            int bill_id = transactionID;
                            int Customer_ID = Convert.ToInt32(txtClientID.Text);
                            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
                            string filename = dlg.FileName;
                            decimal total = Math.Round(decimal.Parse(txtGrandTotal.Text), 2);
                            tdal.UploadFile(filename, bill_id, Customer_ID, total,date);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        scope.Complete();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: you find `public void PrintNoDisplay` and replace `printDoc.Print();`so that ot doesn't print instead creates a memerystream, which you use to store

Comment: With what should I replace printDoc.Print()? Could u help me with some lines of code? How can I upload that memorystream on MySQL, because with the code I have right now I need to select the file through OpenDialog?

Comment: that is something you have to do, set a halting poing in the function abouve and check the options given.

Comment: If I knew how to do it, I wouldn't have asked... Thanks anyway :)

Comment: i told you how, but programming you dee to do on your own and check which methis an object has. is basic